# Calling a get function of wcf throws CommunicationException

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I've two projects. One having wcf service and database. Other used for calling these functions. If I call a function of webservice which adds something to the database it works fine. But when I call a function which retrieves something from database. I get CommunicationException. The function I'm calling in WebService.svc.cs is:

```
public List<Artist> GetAllArtists()
        {
            Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities();
            return (db.Artists).ToList();
        }
```

And I'm calling it like this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceReference2.WebServiceClient o = new ServiceReference2.WebServiceClient();
        Artist [] artists = o.GetAllArtists(); //Exception arises here
        string str = "";
        foreach (Artist artist in artists){
            str += artist.ArtistID + " ";
        }
        Response.Write(str);
        gv.DataSource = artists;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
```

Exception:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
>   HResult=-2146233087 Message=An error occurred while receiving the HTTP
>   response to http://localhost:23060/WebService.svc. This could be due
>   to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details. Source=mscorlib StackTrace: Server stack trace: at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException
>   webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>            at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message
>   message, TimeSpan timeout)
>            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>         Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>            at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>            at WebLab6AlbumManagementSystemClient.ServiceReference2.IWebService.GetAllArtists()
>            at WebLab6AlbumManagementSystemClient.ServiceReference2.WebServiceClient.GetAllArtists()
>   in c:\Users\Muhammad Rehan\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebLab6AlbumManagementSystemClient\Service
>   References\ServiceReference2\Reference.cs:line 567
>            at WebLab6AlbumManagementSystemClient.ViewAllArtists.Page_Load(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Muhammad Rehan\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2013\Projects\WebLab6AlbumManagementSystemClient\ViewAllArtists.aspx.cs:line
>   16
>            at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender,
>   EventArgs e)
>            at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
>            at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>            at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>
> InnerException: System.Net.WebException
>            HResult=-2146233079
>            Message=The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
>            Source=System
>            StackTrace:
>                 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>                 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan
>   timeout) InnerException: System.IO.IOException HResult=-2146232800
>   Message=Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. Source=System
>   StackTrace: at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer,
>   Int32 offset, Int32 size) at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[]
>   buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) at
>   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean
>   userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead) InnerException:
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException HResult=-2147467259 Message=An
>   existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>   Source=System ErrorCode=10054 NativeErrorCode=10054 StackTrace: at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size, SocketFlags socketFlags) at
>   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset,
>   Int32 size) InnerException:

Comment: Is `Artist` a `DataContract`?

Comment: It's OperationContract. I mean GetAllArtists() is OperationContract. Whereas there is nothing written on the top of Artist and Artist is generated from the db automatically using ado.net entity data model from database.

Answer (score 0):

All WCF error messages are so cryptic, that it is always unknown what caused the error itself.
It is very likely that the reason of your error is some serialization problem.
Try to add logging or write a test to serialize your array of artists using DataContractSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference2.WebServiceClient o = new ServiceReference2.WebServiceClient();
    Artist [] artists = o.GetAllArtists().ToArray(); //Exception will not //come now
    string str = "";
    foreach (Artist artist in artists){
        str += artist.ArtistID + " ";
    }
    Response.Write(str);
    gv.DataSource = artists;
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

Check in the Service Settings that the collection default type is selected as Array or List. I think in your case it is set to List, because Service is returning List while here you are assigning it to Array variable.So try adding .ToArray() or change Default to Array.